# authenticate swing application with spring security

Tags: java, spring, swing

Is it possible to authenticate desktop application written in swing using existing spring security configuration (I have all the classes SecurityConfig.java, UserDetailsService.java, SecurityWebAppInitializer.java and they are tested) and it works properly with web application?
I need to authenticate with backend (spring) somehow from the swing application.
I know a way how to achieve something like this using JDBC and fetching the credentials direct from the database.

If it is not possible what else can I do in order to get this done?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your SWING application communicating via HTTP witht the spring based server or is it a fat client which has it's own "server code"?

Comment: the authentication itself can be over HTTP but the communication from server to swing app should be over web ocket. I suppose I need some kind of java library for the web socket communication. Thank you